# The button doesn't work according to the action

Tags: django, django-models, button, django-views, django-templates

By pressing this button, the seller must close the sell and no one else can bid.
This button should be visible only to the seller.
However, it is visible to everyone and does nothing.

The form is related to the creation of the product page and has a field with the user's name.

Thank you in advance for your ideas:)

views.py:

```
def close_bid(request,  product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
    bid_info = get_object_or_404(Bid_info, pk=product_id)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = request.user
            if user.is_authenticated:
                if user.id == ProductForm.user.id:
                    bid_info.checkclose = True
                    product.active_bool = True
                    product.save()

  return redirect('page_product', product_id=product.id)
```

page_product.html:

```
{% if product.active_bool and Bid_info.checkclose %} 
    <p>This is close!</p>
{% else %}
    <form method="post" action="{% url "close_bid" product.id %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
   </form>
{% endif %}
```

models.py:

```
class Product(models.Model):  
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    seller_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    active_bool = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Bid_info(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seller")
    bid_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    checkclose = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    winner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, 
                                                                blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the template to stop is appearing. It also doesn't do anything. Presumably you want to submit the form.  So

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Close</button>
```

will make it submit the form, which will then 404 if done by the wrong user. To hide the button using the same logic as in the view,

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and request.user.id == ?? %}
       <button type="submit"  ...
{% endif %}
```

You don't show the view which renders `page_product.html` hence the ?? above. You may need to add something to the context against which it is rendered.

Personal opinion ... it's all so much easier using Class-Based Views!

Comment: HI, with these conditions, the button isn't displayed at all, and if this condition is removed, it will get this error `type object 'ProductForm' has no attribute 'user'`.   However, the form has such a field.